# Trying to reshape my numpy array to have an extra dimension

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, keras

I am currently using this code to get a greyscale image representation of an image and represent it in the format of a `(512, 370, 1)` array.

```
img_instance = cv2.imread(df.iloc[i][x_col]) / 255.
img_instance = cv2.resize(img_instance, (target_size[1], target_size[0]))
mask_instance = cv2.imread(df.iloc[i][y_col], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) / 255.
mask_instance = cv2.resize(mask_instance, (target_size[1], target_size[0]))
print(mask_instance.shape)
mask_instance.reshape(target_size[0], target_size[1], 1)
print(mask_instance.shape)
```

The first print, I get a `(512, 370)`, followed by a `(512, 370)` on the second print statement too. This is a problem for me, as I am trying to build a Keras model where I have a layer that looks like the layer below to which I am trying to fit the mask instance to.

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)              (None, 512, 370, 1)  17          activation_18[0][0]
```

Comment: `mask_instance = mask_instance[:, :, np.newaxis]` is another way of adding a trailing dimension to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `reshape` does not work in-place!
- the shape must be a tuple.

.

```
mask_instance = mask_instance.reshape((target_size[0], target_size[1], 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `np.reshape()` does not add a dimension, but the correct function to use is `mask_instance = np.expand_dims(mask_instance, axis=2)`. The axis is 2 because the backend is operating on a channels last model.